# Downloading a zip file to local drive with PHP and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I am using WordPress for a web site, and would like to include a menu item to download a zip file from the web site to the local drive. I tried using the following function:

```
function download_binary_file($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $base_name = basename($file);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$base_name.'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

But when this function is executed, instead of getting a dialog to save the file, the contents of the zip file are displayed in my browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Displayed in what way?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `ob_clean();` and `ob_flush()` ? And are you sure you have no output before header()? + have you tried another browser?

Comment: Mostly non-ASCII characters. Essentially, the file is dumped into the browser window.

Comment: To John: it does not work, it says that the header has already been sent, which is a side effect of using WordPress

Comment: Remove the ob stuff but wrap all of this in the init hook. `add_action( 'init', function () { // Your code } );` - I don't know if your code works but now you won't have the header has already been sent problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your zip file, then create the menu item, then add a htaccess redirect from the menu item to the zip file url. Zip files usually auto download.. I know there are also download manager plugins for wordpress, that make the process pretty easy.

Comment: htaccess redirect? no, it's not that complicated, I can simply provide a link with the zip file name in it, but this is not my question